# Extract MSER detected areas (Python, OpenCV)

Tags: python, opencv, bounding-box, mser

I can't extract the detected regions by MSER in this image:

[image: img]

What I want to do is to save the green bounded areas.
My actual code is this:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

mser = cv2.MSER_create()
img = cv2.imread('C:\\Users\\Link\\img.tif')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
vis = img.copy()
regions, _ = mser.detectRegions(gray)
hulls = [cv2.convexHull(p.reshape(-1, 1, 2)) for p in regions]
cv2.polylines(vis, hulls, 1, (0, 255, 0))

mask = np.zeros((img.shape[0], img.shape[1], 1), dtype=np.uint8)
mask = cv2.dilate(mask, np.ones((150, 150), np.uint8))
for contour in hulls:
    cv2.drawContours(mask, [contour], -1, (255, 255, 255), -1)

    text_only = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask=mask)


cv2.imshow('img', vis)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.imshow('mask', mask)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.imshow('text', text_only)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Expected result should be a ROI like image.

[image: out]

Source image:

[image: src]

Comment: How do you want to 'save' them? One image per region, no matter the size? Extracting sub-arrays of those regions? Could you clarify what's the expected result?

Comment: @GPhilo edited the question

Comment: Have a look here: https://www.bytefish.de/blog/extracting_contours_with_opencv/

Comment: Was reading it right now...do you think it will work with images which contains numbers so small ?

Comment: Canny filter (or blur+threshold) could make them big enough for this. Otherwise use findContours or MSER to find big white patches, like you did above, and use those as your mask. But as GPhilo said you can only save rectangular images, using a rounded contour may be useful only to leave out some noise.

Comment: Alright, so it's official that I can't save MSER shapes with content inside..

Comment: @lorenzo found it [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15341538/numpy-opencv-2-how-do-i-crop-non-rectangular-region](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15341538/numpy-opencv-2-how-do-i-crop-non-rectangular-region)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just get the bounding box for each contour, use that as a ROI to extract the area and save it out:

```
for i, contour in enumerate(hulls):
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
    cv2.imwrite('{}.png'.format(i), img[y:y+h,x:x+w])
```

Comment: Did you tried it ? I am asking because it doesn't work. I mean, it save "something" (debris for most the files) but it's not ok. I like, instead, the way to count the files with formatting strings.

Comment: Can't try it because I don't have sample data to run it on, it is possible I swapped x and y coordinates in `img[...]`. Can you please try running it with `img[y:y+h, x:x+w]` instead and see if that fixes it?

Comment: Yes, the coordinates was swapped. Now it works. Just to know, the code above is standard to saving bounding boxes (I mean x,y,w,h ...) ?

Comment: Thanks, fixed the answer with the right coord order.
In python, OpenCV's `boundingRect` returns a 4-tuple `(x,y,w,h)`, which I extracted directly in the 4 values because I needed them for the array indexing. Ideally, if you need to store the bounding box, you'd keep the 4-tuple as it was.

Comment: Can you show me also how to order them ? They are being saved "wildly".

Comment: They are being saved in the order they are in `hulls`, so if you want them to be sorted in some way you need to sort that list

Comment: EDIT: did it...was simple.

Comment: sorry if I bother you, but I am curios about one thing: the code you suggested create a bounding box around detected areas and then it is being saved, box by box.
But what if I want to save the shape MSER detect ? Not to create a box around each char but to extract it the exact shape. Do you know how to do ?
Thanks

Comment: You can only save rectangular images, that's why I get the bounding box. If you want the shape, what you can do is save the data from the multiplication of the input image and the mask (i.e., the third image in your question), that way you'll have a black outline that you can remove afterwards in your processing

Comment: But which is the variable to save here  as mask ? I tried to imwrite text-only but it save me all the image, not a single ROI..

Comment: found it [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15341538/numpy-opencv-2-how-do-i-crop-non-rectangular-region](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15341538/numpy-opencv-2-how-do-i-crop-non-rectangular-region)

Answer (score 4):

detectRegions also returns bounding boxes:

```
regions, boundingBoxes = mser.detectRegions(gray)

for box in boundingBoxes:
        x, y, w, h = box;
        cv2.rectangle(vis, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 1)
```

This draws green rectangles, or save them as mentioned in GPhilo's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Hey found a cleaner way to get the bounding boxes

```py
regions, _ = mser.detectRegions(roi_gray)

bounding_boxes = [cv2.boundingRect(p.reshape(-1, 1, 2)) for p in regions]
```

Comment: As Mansite already mentioned, detectRegions actually returns these bounding boxes in the second returned argument (which you denote as _)