# Save shape of MSER (Python, OpenCV)

Tags: python, opencv, shapes, mser

The question is this: how can I save the shape a MSER image give me as output ? I already [received an answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47595684/extract-mser-detected-areas-python-opencv/47596008#47596008) but using bounding boxes.
What I want is to save the shape as it seems to result a bit more accurate than a box.

For the code I am using, take a look at the answer linked above. The output should be a single shaped-ROI extracted from this image (look at text window):

[image: example]

Comment: You can not ssave a shaped roi as an image... images are rectangles (always)... But you can save it with black (or any distinguishable color) around it... or you can save the mask as well, or you can save the points to a xml/csv or any other format to be able to reproduce it on load...

Comment: But can I copy this shape ? The way could be this: with another script I create a blank image and from this one I copy the shape to the other. I will have a shape inside a (white) rectangle....hmmm...now that I think, if this work, it could be the solution..

Comment: The shape is just a collection of points... you can save a collection of point in several ways, for instance numpy, or directly to a file that you load